# How to debug drools decision table

Tags: drools

Could someone help me how to debug a decision table in Drools. For our project we are creating a decision table with more than 1000 rules. Whenever their is a mistake in a rule who spreadsheet is not working and also its not displaying where is the exact error.

Answer (score 3):

**Drools: version 7.15.0.Final**

I currently follow two approaches for debugging decision tables:

## Compilation phase

In my case, I have to serialize the decision tables to save time –– normally they're converted into the `.drl` files which are then evaluated. I skip the line and compile them directly and get the knowledge bases and serialize them. My application uses these serialized knowledge bases.

Sometimes my decision tables fail to compile.

I debug them by generating the `.drl` file. The errors that drl parser generates are mostly identifiable from the generated `.drl` file.

[Code snippet for converting a drools decision table into its corresponding drl file](http://techalpine.com/how-to-convert-decision-table-excel-spread-sheet-to-a-drl-file-in-drools/)

## Runtime phase

Sometimes, even if my decision tables have compiled successfully, they have some runtime issues –– some rules don't fire as expected. To debug these I've found the use of `AgendaEventListener` helpful. Drools provides two helpful agenda event listener implementations for debugging purposes out of the box: `DebugAgendaEventListener` and `DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener`.

There are two variations of the `DebugAgendaEventListener` and `DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener`. The ones from the `org.drools.core.event` package use the `Logger` instance for logging the events where as the ones from `org.kie.api.event.rule` package use the `stderr`. However, both have the exact same functionality.

Moreover, the Kie Event Model can be leveraged to get more information out and custom debugging. More information can be found [in the drools 7.15.0.Final docs](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.15.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_event_model).

Additional links and references:
https://javadude.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/debugging-drools-rules/